# Причастный оборот перед именем собственным

Tags: пунктуация

> Расстроившаяся из-за сына *Анна* никак не могла взять себя в руки.

Нужна ли перед *Анна* запятая? Я знаю, что если вместо *Анна* было бы местоимение (*она* например), то запятая была бы обязательна.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Возможны оба варианта написания, но вариант с запятой будет отличаться подчёркиванием причинной связи между определением в виде причастного оборота и действиями Анны (этому будет соответствовать и речевая пауза).

http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=127

(Лопатин, § 46 п.2)

Answer (score 1):

Причастный оборот, стоящий перед определяемым словом, обособляется, если имеет добавочное обстоятельственное (чаще всего причинное) значение. Именно это содеоржится в Вашем предложении.